# Display unique count of account states in dashboard component

Tags: dashboard, unique

I would like to have a dashboard component that shows the # of unique states that we have accounts in.  I can get the account by using the unique count feature in a report, but I would like to display this # on a dashboard component.  I would rather not write a Visual Force component to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a report that was grouped by state and had one detail column with the account name.  I then added a summary formula that counted the unique # of states...   ADDRESS1_STATE_CODE:UNIQUE

I was then able to create a dashboard Metric Chart component based on this report that simply shows the count of unique states.